# How to open and load oracle fmb file with C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, oracle, analyzer

I need to know is there any way to open and analyze an oracle form module (fmb file format) in C/C++ and get a list of all used tables, views, blocks,... in that module file.

give me a sample please, thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read the PL/SQL code in an Oracle Forms .FMT file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230248/how-to-read-the-pl-sql-code-in-an-oracle-forms-fmt-file)

Comment: @VladLazarenko - that is not a duplicate, because that question is about editing the *text* version of the FMB file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are talking about is the Forms C/C++ API.  This was a "power user" tool for working with Forms outside the IDE, in a batch mode.  Oracle have deprecated it in favour of the easier to use Java tool, JDAPI.  In fact Oracle appears to have completely eradicated     documentation for the C API from the OTN site.

Fortunately we still have the Wayback Machine.  So, here is [the Developer 2000 documentation for the C/C++ API (warning: PDF)](http://web.archive.org/web/20090306143951/http://oracle.com/technology/products/forms/pdf/274326.pdf).